ASP.NET Core app can't login using negotiate from domain name
I'm having a hard time trying to use negotiate for my app. The thing is that for https://localhost, the Windows authentication works fine, but once I switch to make a request from https://test.com, I keep getting HTTP 401 and the credentials never get loaded in the HTTP context.
I created a quick example to remove noise from my original app and the behavior is the same, can't get it to work:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://test.com");
                      });
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://test.com");

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

I made sure that the CERTs are valid and working and is still the same.
This is what I get when login from the domain name
[11:33:41 DBG] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler] Negotiate error code: CredentialError. 

[11:33:41 DBG] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler] There was a problem with the users credentials. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: UnknownCredentials

Did I miss some configuration for the authentication?

Integrated auth (i.e. NTLM/Kerberos) requires both the web-server and all client machines to be in a Windows Active Directory or Samba+LDAP domain. I note that NTLM is dead because it's insecure so orgs today only use Keberos now - but Kerberos famously does not work over the Internet by design thus making it inappropriate for public websites (and not just because your public web-server and your own personal laptop certainly won't be in the same AD DS domain).

(To clarify my remarks: NTLMv2 (unlike NTLMv1 and Kerberos) does (still) work safely and securely on the public Internet, but browsers have always been awful at handling it (e.g. there's no way to "log-out" on a domain-joined machine; on a non-domain machine users will get an ugly modal popup) - so you only ever see public NTLMv2 being used for things like intranet websites for a small number of users.

Unfortunately my app has to accept Windows Authentication, I found that modifying the DisableLoopbackCheck registry this can be solved, but I'm wondering if its secure to modify that register.

"my app has to accept Windows Authentication" - Please explain why this is a requirement: there will likely be an overall better alternative approach - or provide more background information so I understand your use-case, your users, etc.

DisableLoopbackCheck likely won't fix the problem - all of the articles about it are for Windows Server 2003 and IIS 5.x - I haven't seen anything that confirms it's relevant for modern Windows Server and IIS boxes; even the orignal KB article (KB896861) has been archived now too.

When using Kerberos, the SPN is critical. The SPN must be correctly registered in Active Directory (AD) for the domain name (https://test.com) to ensure that the Kerberos ticket can be correctly issued.

While modifying the DisableLoopbackCheck works, it can have security implications, particularly if your server is exposed to the internet. If possible, consider using other methods like configuring the SPN correctly or using a fully qualified domain name that resolves externally.

Please follow the steps to add DisableStrictNameChecking and BackConnectionHostNames in Registry Editor.

Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
Right-click Parameters, click New, and then click DWORD (32-bit) Value.
Type DisableStrictNameChecking and press ENTER.
Double-click the DisableStrictNameChecking registry value and type 1 in the Value data box, click OK
In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
Right-click MSV1_0, point to New, and then click Multi-String Value.
Type BackConnectionHostNames, and then press ENTER.
Right-click BackConnectionHostNames, and then click Modify.
In the Value data box, type the host name or the host names for the sites that are on the local computer, and then click OK.
Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the IISAdmin service.

NOTE:
The original Microsoft KB links on this answer were broken and have been removed.
This article provided the instructions for setting DisableStrictNameChecking.
And Run Command Prompt as Administrator
net stop iisadmin /y
net start iisadmin

